# The enamel of our teeth are softer/harder at various points in the day? Brushing after a meal harmful to enamel?

Tags: time-of-day, brushing-teeth, enamel, plaque, texture

Growing up, I was always taught to brush my teeth after eating breakfast, but should I be brushing my teeth before breakfast? The reason why I brushed afterwards was to remove the food bits/taste remaining in my mouth so it's fresh and clean for the rest of the day. But one of my friends, working on his degree to become a dentist, says that brushing teeth immediately following a meal is not the optimal time because that's when the enamel in our teeth is the softest... so we could, in fact, be harming our enamel by brushing away at it when it's so soft.

I had no idea that the softness-hardness degree of our teeth's enamel fluctuated in a day.

1. How/why does the soft/hardness of our enamel change in a day? Is it
   temperature? Saliva? Acid?
2. How many times a day does the texture of our enamel change?
3. When is the optimal time to brush our teeth? An hour afterward brushing?